# Sass compiler says: Inconsistent indentation

Tags: sass

I have this in my main.sass:

```
#thing 
{
       -moz-box-sizing:     border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:     border-box; 
            box-sizing:     border-box;
}
```

When compiling, sass says:

```
Inconsistent indentation: 7 spaces were used for indentation, 
but the rest of the document was indented using 4 spaces.
```

**Is there a way to suppress this?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Seeing that you've included the curly braces in your question, I suggest that you try changing the file's extension from `.sass` to `.scss`. SCSS will probably ignore your indentation because it can tell which part goes where based on the curly braces.

---

SASS relies on indentation to tell where you're trying to apply your CSS, so it won't be able to validate it if it varies in every line. Try this instead:

```
.something
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box 
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box
    box-sizing:         border-box
```

Personally, I wouldn't even bother indenting `border-box` to make them all start at the same column, because it's too much work for too little gain. As an alternative, you could write a mixin to do it for you:

```
@mixin border-box
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box
    box-sizing: border-box
```

After defining it, you can include it directly:

```
.something
    @include border-box
```

Comment: I've added the `#thing {}` to the sass. I write sass, not scss. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Try changing the extension to SCSS and testing it with the curly braces. SCSS should ignore inconsistent indentation.

Comment: Darn, you are right! It's scss not sass. If you can make that into an answer I'll approve it. :)

Comment: There. Let me know if it's okay.